# Export from ggplot2 dark theme with no white border?

Tags: r, ggplot2, export, themes

I want my plots to have dark background to match a slide theme that I am using. I have everything the way I want it, but I cannot figure out how to remove the white border from the overall image. I am looking for something like `theme(plot.border = element_line(color = "#1e1e1e"))` but there does not seem to be a `plot.border` attribute.

No matter what I do to my export size, it always includes it. I never even knew there was a border in the past because I was always using white on white, but now it is revealed!

I've tried a bunch of stuff and cannot get rid of that stupid line, and I really don't want to have to crop my images to remove, or take manual screenshots from RStudio :)

Here's the code, and see below for the image it's creating...

```
p<- ggplot(barchart.data, aes(x=x_labs, y=ests, fill=l_labs)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", color=fill_colors, position=position_dodge(), fill=fill_colors) +
  geom_text(aes(y=ests+perrs+0.02, label=sprintf("%1.1f%%", 100*ests)), vjust=0.5, hjust=0, size=bar.font, color="white") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=ests-nerrs, ymax=ests+perrs), width=.2, position=position_dodge(.9), color="white", size=0.25) + 
  labs(title=chtit, x=xaxis, y = yaxis) + 
  theme_classic() + 
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,1.1), breaks=c(0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1)) + 
  theme(legend.position="none", legend.text = element_text(color = "white")) +
  theme(title = element_text(colour = "white")) +
  theme(axis.text = element_text(size=12, color = "white"), axis.line = element_line(color = "white")) +
  theme(axis.title = element_text(size=12, color = "white")) +
  coord_flip() +
  theme(panel.grid.major.x = element_line(colour = "white",size=0.25))+
  theme(aspect.ratio = 1) +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "#1e1e1e")) +
  theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill = "#1e1e1e")) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE))
  return(p)
```

[image: screenshot of plot with unwanted white borderw]

Comment: `grep("border", names(formals(ggplot2::theme)), value=TRUE)`

Comment: yeah... i found that one already... "panel border" is the border around the actual bar chart. i am talking about the outer border that encompasses the chart and the titles and labels as well. when i do a save of this, and import into something like slides or powerpoint on a slide with the same background color, i can see the annoying outer border of the *plot* area (not the *panel* area.

Comment: `element_rect`'s have `colour` _and_ `fill` settings.

Comment: got it - that solved it. i don't know why i didn't see that. i was already using the colour parameter in element_rect for *panel* but didn't think to use it for plot background. thank you!!

Comment: There are _tons_ of theme-ing options. It's super-easy to miss things. Glad the hints helped!